# how to add background color to html email sent with php mail()

Tags: php, html, css, html-email, email

Im trying to add background color to this html email.

Ive tried putting in

- `<script>` tags with css code inside
- bgcolor in body tags
- and a css style sheet

  All of which didnt work.
  Ive read that it could possibly be the provider (gmail) I'm sending these tests to, but there has to be a way.

All the ways I have tested on a separate .html file which has all changed to what I wanted. I just cant get it to in the actual email. I am using the mail() in php.

```
    $message = "
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Rate Your Experience</title>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor = '#0000FF'>
    <center>
    
    <p>
        <h2>How well did '$recipient' do?</h2>
        <h4>Vacancy Title: '$vac_title'</h4>
        <h4>Vacancy ID: '$vac_id'</h4>
    </P>
    </center>
    <center>
        <table>
        <tr>
        <td><h3>we are built on sharing your review with other people who may also want to use this service.</h3></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><h3>Please take a minute to reflect on the level of service youve received.</h3></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><h3>Your review is public - to other employers registered with Ahoy Employ.</h3></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><h3>Should you have any concerns that you would prefer to share in private, please email us at info@website.ca and quote the Vacancy ID shown above.</h3></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </center>
    </body>
    </html>
    ";

    // Always set content-type when sending HTML email
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

    // More headers
    $headers .= 'From: <webmaster@provider.ca>' . "\r\n";

    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Comment: you can write inline-style form email for Example(`<body style="background-color:#0000FF";>`)

Comment: Basic in-line CSS will do what you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Try Like this:**

```
  <body style="background-color:#cfcfcf";>
```

Comment: the inline css worked it just needed singel quotes instead of double.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to know about email is to throw out everything you know about web standards. Email is still in the 90's.  Check out what Litmus and [MailChimp](https://templates.mailchimp.com/development/html/) are saying.

1. Use tables for design.
2. Use tables as containers.  Wrap your entire message in a single column, single row table.

Then [use the bgcolor of that table](https://litmus.com/blog/background-colors-html-email) to color your email's background.

Forget about using an external style sheet or putting CSS in the head with `<style>` tags.  They get stripped out by various readers.  You have to do inline styles in the html tags.

Yes, it defeats the whole purpose of CSS.  But like I said, email doesn't follow standards.  It's waaaay behind.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the email template, then you can write inline css as well embedded css in  tag.

Other wise you can write the inline css in your html code.

- If you are using external css then It will probably not work email at the gmail inbox can not find the path of the css.